cumulative area using cumtrapz / trapz in R
I have seen questions on how to calculate the total area for shaded areas on plots produced using geom_area. The recommended method  to calculate this is to use 'trapz'. The following is the question I have been looking at "Get area size from geom_area (discrete values) [duplicate]"
What exactly is the unit measurement for the value 126.92? Is this Ratio or Time or some other unit?
Sorry if this is obvious!
Also, if anyone has a solution to calculate the area of geom_area then please share!
I have looked at all similar questions and read the R documentation and still none the wiser.

you should provide a data example along with your question

The unit of the area is based on whatever the units of the x and y axis are. For example if x axis is days and y axis is km then the area is km*day
